# How to generate textboxes dynamically based on input number?

Tags: php, javascript

I am doing online shoping webpage.i required to show textboxes based on input number By using onKeyPress Event.

Ex: textBooks  Howmany

```
 PHP Guid     3
```

Then create 3 textboxes with same name PHP Guid in bellow.

like

```
 PHP Guid 
 PHP Guid
 PHP Guid
```

Thanking you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if input number is 5

for($j = 1; $j <= 5; $j++) {

echo "<input type="text"  name="textfield[]">";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Form</title>
<script language="javascript">
function changeIt(count)
{
var i;
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name='mytext'+ i>";
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form" action="post" method="">
<input type="text" name="t1" onblur="changeIt(this.value)">

<div id="my_div"></div>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hima

```
function duplicate() { var l=Number(document.getElementById('textbox name where u r entered')); for($i = 0; $i<l; $i++) { <input type=\’Text\' name=\'group'.$i.'\' id=\'Textbox'.$i.'\' value=\'' pass text box text here '\' >''</input>'; } }
```

this is javascript.

and  babonk  give you solution in php.